# hydro tf::Transform misses .asBt() methods?

Tags: ros, bullet, tf2, tf-conversions, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm moving from fuerte to hydro. As I'm interfacing with bullet directly for physical simulations I regularly used tf::Transform::asBt() which seems to be missing in the tf implementation for hydro. I see that bullet in hydro is now also a system dependency, does is make sense to extend the tf_conversions package with tf_bullet conversion routines or am I overlooking something? Would migrating to tf2 work better in this use case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69676/hydro-tf::transform-misses-.asbt()-methods?/) by [SebastianRiedel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3893/sebastianriedel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Hydro you should use the tf2::convert method to convert datatypes between formats such as tf and bullet.

There's a tutorial here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2/Tutorials/Migration/DataConversions

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1